# Is it reasonable to hold the grade of a student who has graduated?

Tags: ethics, research-undergraduate, grades

My son took an Undergraduate Thesis course this year, and he could not submit his thesis at the end of the school year. Even he has graduated now, he cannot submit his thesis. His advisor insisted that he should finish his current project, then submit the thesis. He got a temporary 80% on his transcript, even though he has published a conference paper and a workshop paper as a co-first author in top tier conferences in the past year.
It seems unreasonable to me and sounds that the professor is holding the grade as a hostage. It would be more proper to let him finish and submit the thesis on whatever the student got in the past year, and the professor judge the thesis and give a fair grade. The ongoing research can be continued as a collaboration and they could submit the paper together if more conclusive results have been obtained.

Comment: I don't understand: Your son has graduated. What grade is missing?

Comment: May I ask why you ask this and not your son?

Comment: I don't see how conference papers are relevant

Comment: How is the "current project" related to the thesis?

Comment: These papers are part of his undergraduate thesis. It is just a course for a year. The thesis should be submitted and graded at the end of school year. My son did his research in the group as well. For research, it carries on. For course, it ends at the end of the school year.

Comment: Why could he not submit his thesis?

Comment: The professor asked him to carry on working and submitted later.

Comment: I ask this because it is not reasonable from my 25 years experience of supervising graduate and undergraduate thesis.

Comment: If the student did not submit the undergraduate thesis by the deadline, the student should have a grade of zero.  Sounds to me like the student is getting a sweet deal.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Short answer is that I can't tell if it's ethical or reasonable given a lot of details are missing in your case. However, I can definitely say, accepting the graduation diploma with an unsettled grade is an incorrect decision. It should be a sustained "incomplete" grade and the student should never have agreed to take an 80% as a make-do grade.

> even though he has published a conference paper and a workshop paper
> as a co-first author in top tier conferences in the past year.

Yet, this is still not the thesis. Unless, the professor had promised (and the burden to show the proof is on the student) that a co-first author conference proceeding will be held as equivalent to the required thesis.

> It seems unreasonable to me and sounds that the professor is holding
> the grade as a hostage. It would be more proper to let him finish and
> submit the thesis on whatever the student got in the past year, and
> the professor judge the thesis and give a fair grade.

An important component that was not clear here is that what the contractual agreement between the student and the professor was. If the thesis proposal has three parts, A, B, C. And the student never finished C, but managed to publish a conference proceeding with materials in A & B. Technically speaking, the thesis is incomplete. And the professor is in the right to withhold the grade.

What is truly fishy to me is that, at least from what I know working in the US, graduation should not be possible unless all grades have been audited and finalized. If the professor gave an 80% and that grade got through audit, and then the student graduated. I really don't know how likely the institute will entertain a transcript revision.

> Anyway I am disappointed that he received no award at the graduation
> event even he got 100% on his other courses this year.

This is really besides the point. I'd suggest using this opportunity as a training for the child, know the right and learn how the system operates. It will be helpful along the way in future. Think about:

- Now that graduation is all done, degree obtained. How much does the student want to get that thesis done? What kind of professional relationship would the student want to have with the said professor?
- If there was alleged exploitation, can the student put together a case and ask for mediation or grievance with the academic department? Who can be the student's advocate?
- If the student decided to follow through and complete the thesis, will the professor really be able to change the grade? What's the buy in? Can there be a documented procedure so that all parties involved (registrar, the department, the student and the faculty) are in agreement?
- Keep written proofs on all communication on this issue from this point and on.

Comment: This is a course for an undergraduate, not a PhD thesis. A course ends at the end of the school year. The teacher must grade the thesis.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson I'm not sure why you remind us it's an undergraduate course. Penguin's answer has nothing to do with a PhD thesis. It sounds like your child did receive a grade (80%) so they could graduate, with the thesis to be finished informally, "offline." It is not clear whether your child agreed to that understanding the implications, or not

Comment: For a PhD thesis, the advisor and the student decide the content of a thesis and a (reasonable) time to graduate. For an undergraduate course, you just submit a thesis at the end of the school year. The professor has the responsibility to accept the thesis and grade it. I never saw this in my entire life. A good undergraduate thesis could lead to a future publication. Yet two top tier publications are not enough for a undergraduate thesis to be accepted? It seems to me that the professor is abusing the student and he has no right not to grade the thesis on time.

Comment: 80% (A-) is a stain on the transcript as all others are A+ and many are 100%. Yet the effort on the research is way more than that on other courses.

Answer (score 0):

Giving an 80% grade pro tem allows it to be increased as needed and is “easy” on all parties.

Giving a higher grade that may need to be reduced is perfectly feasible just harder to do in front of all parties.

Once the thesis is submitted and has its proper grade then the final marks can be ratified.